# What is an ambident substrate?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, terminology

I had to identify whether a few compounds are *ambident substrates* or not.

However, as I did not know the term, I took to googling it, but I could not find any explanation for this group anywhere.

I know about ambident nucleophiles and electrophiles, yet I had never heard of ambident substrates.

Please explain what they are.

Comment: Where did you come across the term? There are also ambident dienophiles.

Comment: @KarstenTheis I was solving a couple of questions from general organic chemistry from a book by the company megacosm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a subsection in *March’s Advanced Organic Chemistry* [1, pp. 450–451] that provides a straightforward definition and a couple of examples:

> #### 10.G.viii. Ambident Substrates
>
> Some substrates (e.g., 1,3-dichlorobutane) can be attacked at two or more positions, and these may be called *ambident substrates*.
> In the example given, there happen to be two leaving groups in the molecule.
> Apart from dichlorobutane, and in general, there are two kinds of substrates that are inherently ambident (unless symmetrical).
> One of these, the allylic type, has already been discussed (Sec. 10.E).
> The other is the epoxy (or the similar aziridine<sup>524</sup> or episulfide) substrate.<sup>525</sup>
> Selectivity for one or the other position is usually called regioselectivity.
>
> [image: epoxy substrate]
>
> Substitution of the free epoxide, which generally occurs under basic or neutral
> conditions, usually involves an S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism.
> Since primary substrates undergo S<sub>N</sub>2 attack more readily than secondary, unsymmetrical epoxides are attacked in neutral or basic solution at the less highly substituted carbon, and stereospeciﬁcally, with inversion at that carbon.
> Under acidic conditions, it is the protonated epoxide that undergoes the
> reaction. Under these conditions the mechanism can be either S<sub>N</sub>1 or S<sub>N</sub>2.
> In S<sub>N</sub>1 mechanisms, which favor tertiary carbons, attack may be expected be at the more highly substituted carbon, and this is indeed the case.
> However, even when protonated epoxides react by what is expected to be an S<sub>N</sub>2 mechanism, attack is usually at the more highly substituted position.<sup>526</sup>
> This result probably indicates signiﬁcant carbocation character at the carbon (ion pairing, for example).
> Thus, it is often possible to change the direction of ring opening by changing the conditions from basic to acidic or vice versa.
> In the ring opening of 2,3-epoxy alcohols, the presence of $\ce{Ti(O\textit iPr)4}$ increases both the rate and the regioselectivity, favoring attack at C-3 rather than C-2.<sup>527</sup>
> When an epoxide ring is fused to a cyclohexane ring, S<sub>N</sub>2 ring opening invariably gives diaxial rather than diequatorial ring opening.<sup>528</sup>
>
> Cyclic sulfates (**108**), prepared from 1,2-diols, react in the same manner as epoxides, but usually more rapidly:<sup>529</sup>
>
> [image: cyclic sulfate substrate]
>
> ---
>
> <sup>524</sup> Chechik, V.O.; Bobylev, V.A. *Acta Chem. Scand. B*, **1994**, 48, 837.
> <sup>525</sup> Rao, A.S.; Paknikar, S.K.; Kirtane, J.G. *Tetrahedron* **1983**, 39, 2323; Behrens, C.H.; Sharpless, K.B. *Aldrichimica Acta* **1983**, 16, 67; Enikolopiyan, N.S. *Pure Appl. Chem.* **1976**, 48, 317; Dermer, O.C.; Ham, G.E. *Ethylenimine and Other Aziridines*, Academic Press, NY, **1969**, pp. 206–273.
> <sup>526</sup> Biggs, J.; Chapman, N.B.; Finch, A.F.; Wray, V. *J. Chem. Soc. B* **1971**, 55.
> <sup>527</sup> Caron M.; Sharpless, K.B. *J. Org. Chem.* **1985**, 50, 1557. See also, Chong, J.M.; Sharpless, K.B. *J. Org. Chem.* **1985**, 50, 1560; Behrens, C.H.; Sharpless, K.B. *J. Org. Chem.* **1985**, 50, 5696.
> <sup>528</sup> Murphy, D.K.; Alumbaugh, R.L.; Rickborn, B. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1969**, 91, 2649. For a method of overriding this preference, see McKittrick, B.A.; Ganem, B. *J. Org. Chem*. **1985**, 50, 5897.
> <sup>529</sup> Gao, Y.; Sharpless, K.B. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1988**, 110, 7538; Kim, B.M.; Sharpless, K.B. *Tetrahedron Lett.* **1989**, 30, 655.

#### Reference

1. Smith, *M. March’s Advanced Organic Chemistry: Reactions, Mechanisms, and Structure*, 7th ed.; Wiley: Hoboken, New Jersey, **2013**. ISBN 978-0-470-46259-1.

Answer (score 9):

I agreed with andselisk's answer. Yet, *Ambident Substrates* are not limited to *March’s* given examples in that answer. A substrate, which can be consecutively acted either as an electrophile of a nucleophile is also called ambident substrate (Ref.1). One of the best example is acetaldehyde or propanaldehyde in aldol condensation:

[image: Ambident Subsrates]

> In 2002, Barbas III & coworkers have reported that L-proline ($\bf{\text{cat1}}$) could catalyze the twofold condensation of propionaldehyde ($\bf{1}$), acting consecutively as a pro-nucleophile and an electrophile, to other aliphatic aldehydes providing lactols, $\bf{3}$, in a moderate yield after intramolecular hemiacetalization (Scheme B)(Ref.2).

**References:**

1. Céline Sperandio, Jean Rodriguez, Adrien Quintard, "Catalytic strategies towards 1,3-polyol synthesis by enantioselective cascades creating multiple alcohol functions," *Org. Biomol. Chem.* **2020**, *18*, 1025-1035 (DOI: 10.1039/C9OB02675D).
2. Naidu S. Chowdari, D. B. Ramachary, Armando Córdova, Carlos F. Barbas III, "Proline-catalyzed asymmetric assembly reactions: enzyme-like assembly of carbohydrates and polyketides from three aldehyde substrates," *Tetrahedron Lett.* **2002**, *43(52)*, 9591-9595 (https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-4039(02)02412-7).